# Unification in Prolog

Tags: prolog, unification

This is a question from a past exam about unification in Prolog.
we were supposed to say if they unified and then the instantiations.

```
f(a,g(b,a)) and f(X,g(Y,X))
```

This unifies quite a = X, g(b,a) = g(Y,X) and is quite straight forward

```
f(g(Y),h(c,d)) and f(X,h(W,d))
```

I dont think this one unifies because of g(Y) =/ X, though h(c,d) does  unify with h(W,d). Though is it possible that X = g(Y) since uppercase X looks until it finds a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does unify, and it does so because `g(Y)` is a term to be evaluated, as well as `a` -- in the first example you pointed.

You can check the evaluation in a prolog interpreter:

```
?- f(g(Y),h(c,d)) = f(X,h(W,d)).
X = g(Y),
W = c.
```

The unification process works in a depth-first fashion, unifying members and returning each of the available answer, until no further combination is possible.

This means the **unification method** is called for `f(g(Y),h(c,d)) = f(X,h(W,d))`, that finds out the available matchings: `g(Y) = X, h(c, d) = h(W, d)`.

Then, the unification is performed upon `g(Y) = X`, that, since there's no further possible reduction, returns `X = g(Y)`.

Then, the same method is called upon the matching `h(c, d) = h(W, d)`, which gives you `c = W`, and no other matching, resulting, thus, in `W = c`.

The answers, after unification, are returned, and it's usually returned `false` to point when no matching/further matching is possible.

As pointed by CapelliC, the variable `Y`, after the unification process, is still unbound. The unification is performed upon unbound variables, which means:

- the unification of `h(c, d) = h(W, d)` returns `h(_) = h(_)`, and this allows the unification to continue, since `h` is a term, and not an unbound var;
- the unification of `d = d` is a matching of terms, and does not form an attribution -- or binding;
- the unification of `c = W` forms an attribution, and the variable `W` is bound to the term `c`, since it was not bound before -- a comparison would be performed otherwise;
- the unification of `X = g(Y)` simply binds the unbound variable `X` to the term `g(Y)`, and `g(Y)` is a term with an unbound variable, since there's no available unification to `g(Y)`.

Regards!

Comment: thanks again, I hope it's complete now (: Would you mind to check an answer of mine on lambda calculus? here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659107/how-to-create-combinators-lambda-calculus-of-data-structures/13679936#13679936